# Using BioAPI to convert and compare two finger print bitmap images

Tags: linux, bitmap, comparison, fingerprint, biometrics

I am developing an application that gets the fingerprint image bmp of a user from the fingerprint reader hardware and sends it to a linux server that has a collection of such finger print bitmaps. The server should cross verify the fingerprint and fetch the record of the previously enrolled user data associated with a matching finger print.

So far I was able to compile BioAPI for linux and create two BIR templates from passwords.
I am unable to find an example of using BioAPI (or similar free fingerprint matching SDKs) to compare two bitmap images or to create a BIR template from such finger print bitmaps.

I would be grateful if anyone can provide any help or suggestions on how to achieve what I am trying to do.

Thanks in Advance
Nikhil Mathew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NIST wrote the public domain [NIST Biometric Image Software (NBIS) package](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm) which includes the BOZORTH3 fingerprint matching algorithm. It's written in ANSI C so it will compile and run on Linux. To use BOZORTH3, you have to first run your fingerprints through the MINDTCT minutiae detector which is also included in NBIS.

See also the [NBIS User Guide](http://www.nist.gov/customcf/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=51097) and the [download link](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nigos.cfm).

Answer (score 0):

So it Seems like You are working in this scenario

- u  are using a finger-print Scanner to capture images of The Fingers(or thumbs)
- Before new enrollment of a thumb-print u need to check that if this person is already Enrolled

If same case is here u not need to Compare two bitmap images of thumb print Bit Map Images are incomparable

instead you should give both bitmap images to the Finger Print Matching SDK
this sdk will create the comparable Templates of the input images
and SDK also provide methods which will take input Templates 
and after comparing those templates it will tell you if Finger Prints Are Matching

i hope this will be helpful to you

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest an SDK you know that would allow me to do the template creation and then comparison ?